# Trigger error when using IN inserted/updated

Tags: sql-server-2008

My trigger does the following:

```
INSERT INTO CRM_CONTACTS_PRERENDER 
SELECT * FROM V_CRM_ADDRESS_00
WHERE CRMID = (SELECT CRMID FROM INSERTED)
```

Now when inserted/updated contains only 1 CRMID I get no problems. But as soon as there are 2 or more the trigger throws an error. Help most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your `WHERE` clause only handles a single (or no) value.  Use `IN` rather than `=`:

```
WHERE CRMID IN (SELECT CRMID FROM INSERTED)
```

to process all of the inserted rows.

Answer (score 0):

Because Select returns a result set, You should use "in" in conditional statement. like:

```
WHERE CRMID in (SELECT CRMID FROM INSERTED)
```